# MVC ASP.NET Overloaded Controller Methods not working properly

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database

(Sorry if all these questions are stupid)

I have two methods in my controller

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Pokemon(int id)
{
    var user = db.PDCUsers
                 .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Username == User.Identity.Name);
    var pkmn = db.PlayerPkmns.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

    return View(new DetailedPokemonViewModel(pkmn, user.Id, user.StepsIncMult));
}
```

and

```
[HttpPost]
[ChildActionOnly]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Pokemon(int id, int steps)
{
    var user = db.PDCUsers.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Username == User.Identity.Name);
    var pkmn = db.PlayerPkmns.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    if (pkmn.CurrentTrainerId == user.Id)
    {
        pkmn.Experience = pkmn.Experience + steps;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return Pokemon(id);
}
```

I'm calling the `Pokemon(int id, int steps)` from inside the `Pokemon(int id)` view by

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Pokemon", "PokemonView", new { id = Model.Id, steps = 5000 })">walk</a>
```

However, when I click the link the the `Pokemon(int id, int steps)`, it doesn't update the database value - and when I put a breakpoint in it doesn't register. I don't think I'm even hitting the method, but the url at the top has the steps parameter concatenated?

All I'm trying to do is update the experience value of a data row by the amount of steps passed as a parameter. I don't want a new view (for now) - I just want it to show the Pokemon(int id) view again.

Is there a best practice for calling a method then returning to the view it was called from? Also, is there any obvious reason why my database values aren't updating/breakpoint isn't being hit?

Thanks

---

Edit:

By using `RedirectToAction` instead of returning the `Pokemon(int id)` method,
and renaming the `Pokemon(int id, int steps)` to avoid overloading httpget issues, it works!

Thanks!

Comment: actions result in a GET request being made. You have tagged the action with POST. Also if you do not want to refresh the view then use AJAX call

Comment: You have to remove `[HttpPost]` from second method.

Comment: I tried removing the HttpPost and it still doesn't update - I'll try messing with AJAX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ChildActionOnly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.childactiononlyattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) attribute ensures that an action method can be called only as a child method from within a view. so you no need to use `[ChildActionOnly]`. you are using `a` for go to the link so it's a `GET` request.

So remove

```
[HttpPost]
[ChildActionOnly]
```

And Change your return statement like:

```
return RedirectToAction("Pokemon", new {id = id});
```

Hopefully it's help for you.

Comment: Thanks! But I've still got some issues
It looks like it's something to do with calling the method - I changed the return in Pokemon(int id, int steps) to return a static value, and the view did not reflect the changes.
I don't think I'm calling the view correctly.

Comment: Thank you! The RedirectToAction is definitely going to solve issues I would have gotten later, but there's still one thing - Having both overloaded methods as httpgets is throwing an error - I'll see what happens if i just rename the pokemon(int id, int steps)
Work's Perfect!